# docker build container that I cannot open

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

Wanted to turn my python script into api using Docker.

This is what the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    software-properties-common \
    git \
    && apt-get install poppler-utils -y \
    && apt-get -y install tesseract-ocr \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y \
    && apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY . .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Docker build container just fine. It is running

[image: Docker]

No errors within the Docker:

[image: inside the container]

> I press the link and its just http://0.0.0.0/

I am using PyCharm and python, so I binded the port in PyCharm too
[image: PyCharm Docker edit]

Did anyone run into similar problem? I am new to Docker and might've missed something obvios, sorry.

I tried adding port manually http://0.0.0.0:80/ and http://0.0.0.0:80/Docs
but nothing shows up.

I build similar project with exactly same parameters but this one doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your program is showing you is what address it has *bound* to. 0.0.0.0 means that it'll accept connections from anywhere and 0.0.0.0 isn't the actual address you need to talk to to reach your program.

You've mapped port 80 in the container to port 80 on the host, so you should be able to reach your program at `http://localhost:80/`. Since port 80 is the default for http, you can also just use `http://localhost/`.